# Warning while starting up tomcat with Oracle 19C compatible ojdbc8.jar

Tags: tomcat, ojdbc, oracle19c

We used to have an environment with Oracle 12C compatible ojdbc8.jar in tomcat/lib.
Which was working fine.

We are upgrading Oracle to 19C and so JDBC drivers.
We downloaded new drivers from : https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-ucp-19c-downloads.html

Having **only** ojdbc8.jar in tomcat/lib, tomcat logs following warning.

```
WARNING: Failed to scan [file:/C:/ApplicationServers/apache-tomcat-9.0.10/lib/oraclepki.jar] from classloader hierarchy
java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre9Compat.jarFileNewInstance(Jre9Compat.java:212)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.<init>(JarFileUrlJar.java:65)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:374)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs(StandardJarScanner.java:309)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.doScanClassPath(StandardJarScanner.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:229)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:262)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:104)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:83)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5098)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor7.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre9Compat.jarFileNewInstance(Jre9Compat.java:209)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\ApplicationServers\apache-tomcat-9.0.10\lib\oraclepki.jar
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:85)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(WindowsFileAttributeViews.java:53)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(WindowsFileAttributeViews.java:38)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:194)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1763)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1222)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:726)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:843)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:246)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:176)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:346)
```

Knowing that Oracle wallet is not being used, how critical it would be to ignore this warning?

is there a way to avoid such warning while server startup? 
OR
Adding oraclepki.jar (and couple of others subsequently) is the only option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just realized that this was taken care of by apache in tomcat 9.0.11.
They have added oraclepki.jar in the skip list. I have verified with this version and no more warnings are logged.

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62560